# Laravel, get relation data

Tags: laravel

I'm kinda new to relations in Laravel.

When I do `dd`of an object, I get this:

```
Collection {#485 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Menu {#484 ▼
      #table: "menus"
      #fillable: array:6 []
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:9 []
      #original: array:11 []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "pivot" => Pivot {#486 ▶}
        "subMenus" => Collection {#items: array:3 [▼
        0 => SubMenu {#488 ▼
          #table: "sub_menus"
          #fillable: array:5 []
          #hidden: array:2 []
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:8 []
          #original: array:10 [▼
            "id" => 16
            "name" => "My name"   <--------- this is what I need to get
            "created_at" => "2018-11-20 15:19:14"
            "updated_at" => "2018-11-20 20:29:34"
```

How can I get the `name`value from the Model `SubMenu` that has a relation with  my dd(model) ?

In `Menu` I got thos relation:

```
public function subMenus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SubMenu', 'menu_submenu', 'menu_id', 'submenu_id')->where('estado', Define::ESTADO_ACTIVO)->orderBy('orden');
}
```

I tried something like:

```
dd($MyMenuObject->subMenus());
```

but not working. Tried with get(), ->submenu, etc.

EDIT: This is my data:

with `dd($perfil_activo->menus);` I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it via

```
$model->subMenus()->first()->name;
```

But since `$subMenus()` is a many-to-many relationship, you should probably do this via a loop:

```
foreach($model->subMenus AS $subMenu){
   $subMenu->name; // Do with as you please.
}
```

Edit: Since `$model` is also a `Collection`, you need to use `->first()` or a loop:

```
$model->first()->subMenus->first()->name;

// OR

foreach($model AS $model){
   $model->subMenus->first()->name;
   // OR
   foreach($model->subMenus AS $subMenu){
       $subMenu->name;
   }
}
```

This is all dependant on how you fetch `$model`; if your Query ends with a `->get()` or `->all()`, it will be a `Collection`. If it ends with `->first()`, `->find()`, etc, it will be a single `Model`.

Comment: I don't get why I get this: `Method subMenus does not exist.`

Comment: Oh, your `$model` is also a Collection, so you'd need to loop or use `->first()`; I'll update.

Comment: I put a image of my real dd in the question

Comment: Well, replace `$model` with `$prefil_activo`, and `name` with `nombre` :) But the concept still stands.

Comment: Thanks! now I'm getting better this relations stuff. Finally I did it with `$perfil_activo->menus->first()->subMenus[0]->nombre` I just need the first element of the array, but I'll loop as you said in case I need it.

Comment: No problem :) Note that `subMenus[0]` and `subMenus->first()` are interchangeable;  look more into what a `Collection` is, and how you can use it's methods to make array access so much easier. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the subMenu names on an array: or object

```
$names=$model->subMenus()->pluck('name'); //object
//or
$names=$model->subMenus()->pluck('name')->toArray();// to array
dd($names);
```